# Можно ли узнать статус пользователя в whatsApp?

Tags: php, node.js, whatsapp

Можно ли через API по номеру человека узнать, в онлайне он сейчас или нет?

Comment: И что вы хотите услышать 'Да возможно' или 'Нет нельзя'...

Comment: ну если можно, то хотя бы наводку как.